# Xorg: High CPU Usage (94%) on Moving Mouse (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, xorg, mouse, xfce, cpu-load

whenever I move my mouse enough it causes high cpu usage. Screenshot provided is on a fresh X session.

[Xorg Taking up a lot of CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJtMN.png)

This also causes some frequent freeze ups if I'm running some other programs e.g gaming.

```
[1075299.085] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[1077813.434] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[1077814.079] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[1077814.246] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[1077814.682] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[1077831.975] (EE) client bug: timer event4 debounce: offset negative (-18ms)
[1077831.975] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
[1077831.975] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: WARNING: log rate limit exceeded (5 msgs per 30000ms). Discarding future messages.
[1120008.128] (II) event4  - Corsair Corsair Vengeance M90 Mouse: SYN_DROPPED event - some input events have been lost.
```

Is there any way for the CPU usage not to be this high?

**EDIT:**

I tried with other mice. The CPU usage appears to increase with the Mouse DPI or to be exact, a generic mouse will cause a CPU usage spike, but not as much as a gaming mouse.

I also checked if I have hardware acceleration enabled.

```
$ glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
```

**EDIT 2:**

CPU is an AMD FX-6350

GPU is AMD RX Vega 56

Comment: Try the Ubuntu Unity Desktop instead of the default Gnome Desktop. I've found the performance much better on my Skylake laptop.

Comment: I'm using xfce though.

Comment: Sorry I missed that tag on my tiny phone :(

Comment: As a comparison I have an AMD Kaveri A8-7600 APU and wiggling my mouse side to side adds about 12% to Xorg (up from 0-0.7 to 12-13% CPU). At the same time Firefox goes up to similar, but I can get above 20% if I wiggle it fast! Curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try changing the mouse polling rate parameter on the *usbhid* Kernel module. You can modify its value on the fly by running as super user

```
echo "4" > /sys/module/usbhid/parameters/mousepoll
```

This changes the polling rate from the default value 0 (i.e. "unlimited") to 4 ms (or 250 Hz).

**Note:** Afterwards you will have to replug your mouse in order to see any effect.

Provided that helps, you could make this change permanent by appending the parameter to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` like so

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbhid.mousepoll=4"
```

Then run

```
update-grub
```

and

```
reboot
```

Comment: In my case the high CPU usage stayed the same. I replugged my mouse.