# Ubuntu 21.04 - high CPU spikes when a mouse is moved

Tags: gnome, xorg, mouse, cpu, 21.04

I have the following issue with CPU on `Ubuntu 21.04`.
It was not the case for me on version 20.10 and previous ones.

When the mouse is moved frequently on my PC I have huge CPU spikes. temp is above 60 C.

`gnome-shell`process loads the CPU.

- CPU - `AMD Ryzen 9 5950X` - **frequency boost** is enabled by default
- GPU - `NVIDIA GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]` - `ZOTAC GeForce® GTX 1080 Mini`
- `nvidia-driver-460 (NVIDIA Corporation: GP102[GeForce GTX 1080 Ti])` - proprietary `driver` is used
- mouse - `Razer Basilisk Ultimate Wireless`
- direct rendering is enabled
- `$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` ==>
  `x11` - Xorg is used by default instead of Wayland as I have NVIDIA on a board.
- Installed gnome extensions:

```bsh
$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 May 24 07:32 .
drwx------ 4 user user 4096 May 25 18:10 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 user user 4096 Oct 29  2020 apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user 4096 Oct 29  2020 auto-move-windows@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com


$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 17  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 May 12 07:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 12 07:34 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 12 07:34 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 12 07:34 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

I tried to reduce mouse poll according to this proposal - [XORG - HIGH CPU Usage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068538/xorg-high-cpu-usage-94-on-moving-mouse-ubuntu-18-04).

All cases from this answer were tried too - [GNOME-SHELL HIGH CPU USAGE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036441/ubuntu-18-04-gnome-shell-high-cpu-usage).

The only thing that helped was to reload `gnome-shell` via `Alt+F2 -> r`. But I need to do it 15 times per day or more in order to disable those CPU spikes.

Could you please advice if it is possible to have a permanent solution for the aforementioned issue so that it won't be necessary to do manual `gnome-shell` reload all the time.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Hi @heynnema! thanks for reply! I've updated the question.

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable `apps-menu` and `auto-move-windows`, and restart gnome-shell, and see if there's any improvement. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I can see: `Desktop Icons`,  `Ubuntu AppIndicators`, `Ubuntu Dock`. All of them are disabled and I can't remove them.

Comment: I didn't ask you to remove/delete any of them. Just turn off the two I mentioned.

Comment: Also upgrade your Nvidia driver to version 465.27 available at https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/

Comment: Unfortunately all the suggestions above did not help. Only update to ubuntu 21.10 helped to resolve the issue.

Comment: Same. I changed gnome to kde to fix problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue,
I'll share this bug report, it helped a lot :
[bug 1900760](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1900760)